# How I can query not the latest AMI image id for EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS CloudFormation template allow to select AMI Image ID for EC2 instance using construction like this

```
ECSAMI:
    Description: AMI ID
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>
    Default: /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2
```

But I can not find parameter path that will point to the specific version of AMI Image.
For example AMI ID for ECS can be queried by this path, that point to the specific version:

`/aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/amzn2-ami-ecs-hvm-2.0.20181112-x86_64-ebs/image_id`

How I can query not the latest AMI image id for EC2? Or where I can full "tree" or paths list of publicly available parameters?
I want something like this

`/aws/service/<ec2>/<amazon-linux-2>/<image-version>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special SSM method you show in your question is provided by AWS to make it easy for users to access the latest version of specific AMIs. The information is published into Parameter Store.

The alternative method is to hard-code the value of the desired AMI in the section of the template that defines the EC2 instance. You will often see example templates that use a Mapping to have different AMI values for each region.

There is no capability to request the a specific AMI aside from provide the actual AMI ID.

Why is this? It is because the SSM method was added as a convenience way of referring to the "latest" or "recommended" AMI. Some background process publishes the appropriate AMI IDs to SSM. It is not intended as a method for cataloging *all* AMIs.

If you really need to search by name, you could create a CloudFormation Custom Resource using AWS Lambda that queries available AMIs by name and then returns the appropriate AMI ID.

Comment: Can you give me a hint or link to documentation where I can read about how to overview all information from Parameter Store? I want to see all parameters that was published by AWS.

Comment: See: [Query for the latest Amazon Linux AMI IDs using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/) Please note that using the Parameter Store to find an AMI is only provided as a convenience. The real way to obtain information about AMIs is to use commands like [describe-images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html).

Comment: Thank you, I know about this article. But it show how to query only one "subtree". Is there exists some way that can list me all available trees? Maybe you are familiar with SNMP, where you can query snmp values by providing some oid like 
`1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0`. But if I will use oid like `1.3` snmpwalk will return list of all values that has oid that starts with `1.3` 
I tried to use these command `aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path /aws/service`, it returns empty list.

Comment: No idea. You are better-off using AIM commands rather than SSM.